# struts2 on tomcat project shows blank page, using Fiddler shows 404 error

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, struts2

my project is using Tomcat 7.0.

The file structure is:

> Project
>
> -src
>
> --project package
>
> ----LogInActon.java
>
> --struts.xml
>
> -WebContent
>
> --Web-INF
>
> ----lib
>
> ------...reference jars
>
> ----Web.xml
>
> --index.jsp
>
> --LogInSuccess.jsp

The struts.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <package name="homeLogin" extends="struts-default">

      <action name="logIn" 
            class="com.myApp.system.main.actions.LogInAction" 
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/logInSuccess.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">/index.jsp</result>
      </action>
   </package>
</struts>
```

the Web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Welcome</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

   <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and the index.jsp (the default home page) is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Log in:</h1>
   <form action="logIn">
      <label for="name">Please enter your name  </label>
      <!--<s:textfield name="username" key="label.name1"/><br/>-->
      <s:textfield name="username"/><br/><br/>
      <label for="pw">Please enter your password    </label>
      <s:password name="pw"/><br/><br/>
      <s:submit value="Log In" align="left"/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The project built successfully without error on Localhost, and totally work as expected; however when we deploy to an online server, it shows a blank page. Using Fiddler I see that the request header is:

```
GET /home HTTP/1.1
Host: dev-dev1.wherego.ca
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

and the response header is:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 02:50:15 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

is it any clue on debugging this??

Comment: Thats a 404 for a non-existant resource. Can you verify the URL you are trying to hit? My best guess is that there is some mix-up in the URL. Which URL you hit on localhost and what URL you are trying on your server?

Comment: Are you using the config-browser plugin for struts2? Might be useful. http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/config-browser-plugin.html

Comment: @SaifAsif in localhost I hit localhost:8080/home , and on server it is xxx.com/home, and different result is returned

Comment: Is tomcat running on port `80` on your server ? By default tomcat is set to listen at port `8080`. Try to change the URL to `xxx.com:8080/home`

Comment: @SaifAsif hmm, I didn't configure that. When using xxx.com:8080/home, the service will timeout; btw I don't know if aws elastic beanstalk would configure their tomcat server to be on port 80..

Comment: Service timeout? Can you check and take a look at the logs of the application on the server ? The port configuration will also show up in the logs.

Comment: @SaifAsif OMG! finally find it! The log says: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class xxx.LogInActon) but I still have no idea what this error means lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, you are facing the `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`

This exception is faced when you have are running your application on a different version of JRE then it was intended for. In short, it is just a version mismatch issue.

The version number `51.0`  shows which JRE version your particular class file is compatible with. `51.0` means JRE 7. And it is most probable, that you are running a different version of JRE on your online server as compared to your localhost.

To fix this issue , make sure that you are launching the application on the same major version of JRE on which it was compiled to. You must have JRE6 installed on your online server that is causing the issue.

To check version of JRE , just fire the command

```
java -version
```

on the console.